# window.location.href not working well in ios device

Tags: jquery, ajax

Issue:
ajax works fine in windows or android device but failed in the iOS device.
It returns an alert box in windows or android device.
Return nothing in iOS device.
I tried :
window.location.href ,  location.href ,  location.assign
but none one works, anyone can help me?

HTML FORM

```
    <input type="text" id="userid" name = 'userid' autofocus>
    <input type="password" id="password"  name ='password'>
    <button type="submit" name ='submit' id ='submit'>Login</button>
```

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
var userid = $('#userid').val();
var password = $('#password').val();
var submit = $('#submit').val();
if (userid != '' && password != '') {
  $.ajax({
    url: "login.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      submit: submit,
      userid: userid,
      password: password
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if (data == 'No') {
        alert("Incorrect match of ID / Password");
      } else {

        alert('Success');
        window.location.href='/main_page.php';

      }
    }
  });
} else {
  alert("Please fill all field");
}
});

});
```

Comment: There's no use of `window.location.href` in the code.

Comment: try `document.location.href` instead of `window.location.href`

Comment: @DevsiOdedra  I tried. still same issue..thanks for the response.

Comment: make sure your else condition working properly.

Comment: try throwing in the reload code piece inside a setTimeout()

Comment: _“It returns an alert box in windows or android device. Return nothing in iOS device.”_ - well if the alert in the line before you tried to change the location did not work either, then it is probably not the latter that’s the actual problem, hm? Go debug your Ajax request then.

Comment: also add error function to catch any errors in your AJAX call.

Answer (score 1):

Ori

```
<button type="submit" name ='submit' id ='submit'>Login</button>
```

After Edit

```
<button type="button" name ='submit' id ='submit'>Login</button>
```

and it worked.
Thanks everyone for helping =)